# Itunes on Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, itunes

Hi is there any way to have itunes on Ubuntu 14.04? I really need to have this option. I have tried the playon linux option but that seems outdated and does not work. I also tried Vitual box but mu computer has USB 3.0 which is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately iTunes does not run very well in Linux. You may be able to run an old version through wine, which you have tried through playonlinux. The other option is to run in virtual machine, you tried it on virtualbox but you could try on VMware player. If I remember correctly, VMware player has support for usb 3.0. VMware player is also free and I have always felt that it was faster than virtualbox too so I recommend you try VMware player.

If that does not work you would probably have to use a windows machine. However If all you want is to transfer some music to an iPod you could use rhythmbox